# Find friends users

Tags: sql

I have a users table that contains various information about the user (name, first name, last name, .........) and a table friendships that contains three columns:

1. user_req: username of the requesting user

2. user_acc: username of the user who accepts or rejects the request for friendship

3. status: 0 if the request is pending, 1 if user_req and user_acc are friends

Now I would like to make a query that returns all users (with all their characteristics: name, surname, username, ...) who are friends of a given user username.

*I have to make a join between the two tables "friend" and "users" but how?*

Comment: By reading any documentation. You can start here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: If you want an answer to this question please spend some time tidying it up to make it more readable. As it stands this is a very low quality question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u
INNER JOIN friendship f ON u.username=f.user_acc
WHERE f.user_acc = ? AND f.status = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this one!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
select * from user, friendship where friendship.user_acc=? and friendship.user_req=user.name and friendship.status=1;
```